# Allow device video display in landscape mode

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and use:

```
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait”/>
```

in order to have the app in portrait orientation. As an exception, I want 
my video to be display in the device orientation (portrait/ landscape).

How can I do that without any new plugins?
Already know the cordova plugin to enable this but they made my app bugs.

Comment: how can you connect with cordova wrapper for `device orientation` without using plugins ?

Comment: You can't do this without using a plugin. Setting the above preference fixes the orientation in the native application configuration and it cannot be changed once set.